# make a windows service from executable

Tags: windows, service

I'm looking for a way to create a Windows service from an executable that is not a service itself. Do I need a wrapper service to response Windows service calls that calls non-service process?

**Note:** I'm familiar with SC.EXE and how to make a service. unfortunately when starting services made from non-service executable, I'm getting 1053 timout error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look on how to use **srvany.exe**, it should be a tool allowing to launch an app as a service.